# Printing a String in italics

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am taking input as strings from a `Userform` and I need to output them in a cell. In the output, all the strings are concatenated but only a few them italicized. I am unable to output the strings italicized. I have tried searching the documentation, stack exchange and few other blogs but all of them require selection from a cell rather than manipulating the string obtained from `Userform`. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Output now: [1] R. Welder. How to weld. Welding Shop: Publisher, 2014, pp. 25-32.

Desired Output:[1] R. Welder. *How to weld*. Welding Shop: Publisher, 2014, pp. 25-32.

```
Private Sub Ok_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim bookAuthor, bookTitle, loc, publish, yearBook, pageBook As String

'Make Sheet2 active
 Sheet2.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Format Information
bookAuthor = Author.Value + ". "
bookTitle = TitleOfBook.Value + ". " 'Needs to be Italicized
'bookTitle.Font.Italic 'Error: Object Required
'TitleOfBook.Font.Italic = True 'Italicizes in userform but not in cell
loc = Location.Value + ": "
publish = Publisher.Value + ", "
yearBook = Year.Value + ", "
pageBook = "pp. " + Pages.Value + ". "

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "[" + CStr(emptyRow) + "] " + bookAuthor + bookTitle + loc + publish + yearBook + pageBook

Unload Me
End Sub'
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: "I get an error" is not a useful problem description. You know what that error is, because you have it right in front of you. There is absolutely no reason to fail to include it in your question. What code do you use for `Font.Italic`, and what **specific** error do you get? We can't debug code for you that you don't include in your question.

Comment: Just a remark regarding your code: the line `Dim bookAuthor, bookTitle, loc, publish, yearBook, pageBook As String` will only declare `pageBook` as string, all other variables will be `Variant`.

Comment: *Always* the *last* word? What rule determines what word/s you want in italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the font style of the cell your writing into as its the cell that's italic, not the string;

```
With Range("A1")
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Value = "Roast Beef"
End With
```

**Edit**; To italicize part of the cell select its content by offset and length:

```
emptyRow = 1
bookAuthor = "R. Welder."
bookTitle = "How to weld"
loc = "Welding Shop"
publish = "Publisher"
yearBook = "2014"
pageBook = "pp25-32"

Dim temp As String, begin As Long
'// store everything upto the start of italic part
temp = "[" & emptyRow & "] " & bookAuthor & " "
'// store its length
begin = Len(temp)

With Range("A1")
    '// set the value to everything
    .Value = temp & bookTitle & " " & loc & " " & publish & " " & yearBook & " " & pageBook
    '// we know where the italic text need to be
    .Characters(begin + 1, Len(bookTitle)).Font.Italic = True
End With
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I need to italicize only a part of the letters in the cell. Say only "Beef" from "Roast Beef".

Comment: Alex, is there a general way to do it? Say the two strings "Roast" and "Beef" could change depending on user input. Say the user entered "Unroasted" and "Ham" instead. How could I always make the second string ("Ham", "Beef") italicized? I could use counters to keep count of the length of string and use the method you showed above but just wondering if there might be a better method.

Comment: I am trying to output a concatenation of 6 strings with only the second one italicized. The length of each string could vary depending on user input.