# Insert tags around italicized strings

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and trying to write a script that inserts XML tags around italicized text in Excel. I discovered this question: [VBA Excel Changing Italics and adding </ and />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646967/vba-excel-changing-italics-and-adding-and)

The first answer has a clever approach and I'm modifying that code. It works as is for the first italicized string in a cell, but not for subsequent strings.

Here is the code I'm trying. It loops through each character until it finds the first Italics and inserts a tag and turns the lngCount variable to True. When it finds regular text, if the lngCount variable is True, it inserts the end tag and resets the variable to False.

It works perfectly in some cells, but in other places it doesn't insert the end tag, it others it doesn't insert any tags. Since I can't figure out any consistent differences to when it works well and doesn't, can anyone help? Am I misunderstanding anything about vba?

```
Sub EmphTags()
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngFinish As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each rngCell In rngConstants.Cells
            lngCount = False
            lngStart = 0
            lngFinish = 0
            For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Text)
                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Color = 0 Then
                    If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic Then
                        If lngCount = False Then
                            lngStart = n
                            rngCell.Characters(lngStart, 0).Insert "<emph render='italic'>"
                            rngCell.Characters(lngStart, 22).Font.Italic = True
                        End If
                        lngCount = True
                    ElseIf lngCount = True Then
                        lngFinish = n
                        rngCell.Characters(lngFinish, 0).Insert "</emph>"
                        rngCell.Characters(lngFinish, 7).Font.Italic = False
                        lngCount = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
        Next rngCell
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop:

```
For n = 1 To Len(rngCell.Text)
```

`Len(rngCell.Text)` only gets evaluated once (when you first enter the loop).  Instead of `For...Next`, use a `Do While` loop or similar,  so you can "keep up" with the changes in length caused by adding your tags.

**EDIT**: in light testing this worked for me

```
Sub EmphTags()

    Const TAG_EMPH_START As String = "<emph render='italic'>"
    Const TAG_EMPH_END As String = "</emph>"

    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    Dim isItalic As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then

        For Each rngCell In rngConstants.Cells

            lngStart = 0
            n = 1

            Do While n <= Len(rngCell.Text)

                If rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Color = 0 Then

                    isItalic = rngCell.Characters(n, 1).Font.Italic

                    If isItalic And lngStart = 0 Then lngStart = n

                    If Not isItalic And lngStart > 0 Then
                        TagText rngCell, lngStart, n, TAG_EMPH_START, TAG_EMPH_END
                    End If

                End If
                n = n + 1
            Loop

            'deal with cases where terminal character(s) are italic
            If lngStart > 0 Then
                TagText rngCell, lngStart, n, TAG_EMPH_START, TAG_EMPH_END
            End If

        Next rngCell

    End If
End Sub

Sub TagText(rngCell As Range, ByRef lngStart As Long, ByRef lngEnd As Long, _
              tagStart As String, tagEnd As String)

    rngCell.Characters(lngStart, 0).Insert tagStart
    rngCell.Characters(lngEnd + Len(tagStart), 0).Insert tagEnd
    lngEnd = lngEnd + Len(tagStart) + Len(tagEnd)
    lngStart = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I know, right now I'm compensating for the new text by making sure its italicized or not so It will be ignored, but I don't understand how a Do While loop will help me. I'm still looping through each character in the cell I need the end tag to be inserted in the same loop. What I think you're saying is that if I have only a small amount of text, inserting more characters extends the string and it will stop looping once it reaches the original string length. This isn't how its behaving though when I test it.

Comment: Actually, the more I play with it that seems to be exactly what is happening. I still don't know how a Do while loop helps me. The count isn't really a counter, its really a Boolean switch.